Make MAUI App Icon for Windows transparent
In my .NET 8 MAUI application, I'd like to change the icon from Windows. I like to have an icon like for example Outlook: the background transparent.

At the moment, the icon has a white background. I tried to change the project
<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" 
          Color="#FFFFFF" BaseSize="128,128" />

If I change the Color to Transparent, the background is still white. On the Microsoft documentation, there is nothing related to the background.

Google for a site to convert png to svg, it works on Android and iOS not tested in Windows

The icon is already in svg.

I meant to remove its Background, try this site https://mediamodifier.com/svg-editor#

I want you to be sure it is Transparent first, then try those options in MauiIcon, there's a config file for appicon it should be modified as well, later I can give you full answer.

Ah ok, the file has a transparent background already.

Don't forget to  clean the solution, uninstall the app  and then deploy it again.

It's always good to use SVG for good image scaling.
In my case this worked for me:
(remove color parameter)
<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" />


Unfortunately, removing the Color does not making the background transparent

@Enrico you may need to Clean and Rebuild the solution.
